# Laravel 4.2.8 Blade bad rendering

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have some problem with Blade engine.There ara display differences in rendering between Blade output and "pure" template. I put screenshots from Chrome:

1. Without using Blade (everything is ok):
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxDuK.png
2. With Blade:
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dDHa.png

On the top is fragment of bookmarks bar. As you can see, on second screen there is some white space on the top of page. And there are some differences in table displaying. But it's not all - in developer console everything from head sections now is on the top of body section (only on Blade rendering).
After  tag there's some white space in brackets in many lines, which occours after rendering and below as I told properties from head section.

Some notes from debugging - please, read it:

- on every browser problem occours (Chrome, Firefox, IE)
- there's UTF-8 encoding without BOM. To be sure, I converted every file of template.
- on another templates / simple html pages this same problem
- I switched application mode (dev / prod), but nothing changes
- in app config encoding is of course UTF-8
- I installed Laravel in another place - this same problem
- there's no additional pluggins installed
- Windows 7, Apache
- pure HTML files hosted on server, requests made using server, not as local files (http://.. instead of file://..)

And another problem, maybe connected with this - Artisan - below copy of text from console:
"C:\STRONY\studiobazyli>php artisan

´╗┐´╗┐´╗┐´╗┐´╗┐´╗┐´╗┐´╗┐´╗┐´╗┐´╗┐Laravel Framework version 4.2.8

Usage:..."
As you can see output from artisan simple running starts with strange characters. This same on another commands (migrations etc.). It looks there are encoding problems.

Comment: view the page 'source' - what is in the blank space? Use the dev tools to see what is causing it to appear, then you can debug from there...

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/1mQUjOh.png - this, and below content of original head section